# How to create referrer url in Django view

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following code in a class view:

```
    if event.has_user_edit_credentials(user):
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('edit_event_artists', args=(event.pk,)))
    else:
        return redirect([XXXXXXX])
```

How can I redirect to the referring URL in the `[XXXXX]` field?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the request object's [META dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

```
return redirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Since `HTTP_REFERER` might not be set, it will redirect to the root `/`, you can change this to whatever you want the default redirect destination to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class-based view, I believe the answer lies in the `dispatch` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch)) method. There isn't much detail in your question, so I am afraid I can't formulate a much more detailed answer in response.

If you are using this in a decorator, say perhaps as part of a custom `login_required` sort of thing, `HttpResponseRedirect` would be more appropriate. The same is true if you are using this in a function based view.